# Can we update multiple records with a single PUT request in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, angular, http, service

I am trying to update multiple records through a single put request using Angular HTTP service, which in turn is consuming a Node JS Express API that handles a PUT request. But so far the examples I have seen on the internet a referring to update a single record through a put request. But instead I want to pass an array of objects into the Put request from Angular Http service and it should be able to read that collection in Node JS API. So far I have been passing one single object as a part of request and I could read it's properties via "req.body.propertyname". Can it read the whole array which i want to pass ?

Let's say this is my code on Angular side to update a single book through a put request as below :

updateBook(updatedBook: Book): Observable {
    return this.http.put(`/api/books/${updatedBook.bookID}`, updatedBook, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    });
  }

On Node js front it is able to read the passed book object from client(Angular ) side like below:

.put(function(req, res) {

```
    var data = getBookData();

    var matchingBooks = data.filter(function(item) {
        return item.bookID == req.params.id;
    });

    if(matchingBooks.length === 0) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
    } else {

        var bookToUpdate = matchingBooks[0];
        bookToUpdate.title = req.body.title;
        bookToUpdate.author = req.body.author;
        bookToUpdate.publicationYear = req.body.publicationYear;

        saveBookData(data);
        res.sendStatus(204);

    }
});
```

My question is if I could pass the collection of books at once so that all of them gets updated with a single request ?

updateBook(updatedBooks: Book[]): Observable {
    return this.http.put(`/api/books`, updatedBooks, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    });
  }

If yes then how Node JS could even read this Array passed from client. Will req.body contain this array passed ?

Comment: Well .. a PUT is basicly a form of POST. So yeah, you can send data (like for example an object array). Don't have much experience with NodeJS, but yes, NodeJS should recieve the data as JSON in the body. So you need to extract the data from the body. You could also do it with POST, it would still be in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since we are passing data using the PUT method. In your case, you can send the data to be updated as an array of objects. If you are using MongoDB as your database, you can update data using [Update Array Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/).

**My suggestion:**
The thing is, there is nothing much to be done in the front end. If you need to update an only single record, then pass the single data as an object inside the array. If you want to update multiple records, pass every record as an object inside the array to the backend.

In the backend side, we can receive the data using req.body.books (The name of the object you pass from the frontend). If you are using mongoDB, you can refer to the link on how to store data in an array.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening, I tried this solution and found that instead of wrapping up in "req.body.books" it is wrapping the array in the form of JSON to "req.body" only. But thanks for telling that it's possible to do multiple updates.

Answer (score 0):

Im also new to node js but i tried to update multiple values through postman and i hit the '/api/books' , the below code worked for me and updated all the values at once in my DataBase using PUT call . Used Mongo DB and Node JS

```
app.put('/api/books',(req,res)=>{
    var updatedData="";
    var headersAgain=false;
    for(let i =0;i<req.body.length;i++){
        DataBaseName.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body[i]._id)
        .then(val=>{
            val.url=req.body[i].title
            val.position=req.body[i].author
            val.auto_scroll=req.body[i].publicationYear
            updatedData=val+updatedData
             
            val.save((err,updatedObject)=>{
                console.log('inside save.....',updatedData)
                if(err){
                    return res.status(500).send(err)
                }else{
                    if(!headersAgain==true){
                        headersAgain=true
                        return res.status(201).send(updatedData)
                    }
                }
            })
        })
     }
       
   })
```